# SQL Select valid Geometries without using MakeValid

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlgeometry

I have a large table of data with SQLGeometry values in it.  Many of the rows contain "not-well-formed" Geometries according to OGC ([Geometry.STIsValid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stisvalid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)).  This causes many of my Geometries to throw an error when I check the [Geometry.STGeometryType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stgeometrytype-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017).

When I use this SQL Query I assumed incorrectly that it would leave out the invalid Geometries:

```
SELECT [Geometry] FROM Features 
  WHERE [Geometry] IS NOT NULL
    AND [Geometry].STIsValid() = 1
    AND [Geometry].STGeometryType() = 'Point'
```

The `STGeometryType()` function throws this error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly. System.ArgumentException: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.ThrowIfInvalid() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeometryType()

I get the same error using a sub-query:

```
SELECT G.* FROM (
  SELECT [Geometry] FROM Features 
    WHERE [Geometry] IS NOT NULL
     AND [Geometry].STIsValid() = 1
) AS G
   WHERE G.[Geometry].STGeometryType() = 'Point'
```

Using the [Geometry.MakeValid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/makevalid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) function is not a workable solution, I cannot have SQL Server arbitrarily changing my Geometries but I need to be able to tell what type they are for a View like this one:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Points
AS
  SELECT [Geometry] FROM vwValidFeatures 
    WHERE [Geometry].STGeometryType() = 'Point'
```

**Does anyone have a better solution or a workaround for this?**

*The best solution I can come up with is to select all the Geometries [STAsText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stastext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) and then parse the string because `STAsText()` does not throw any errors if it is invalid.*

Comment: Note: at the time I posted this, I have still not isolated which rows are throwing the errors, when and if I do, I will post an example

Comment: I posted an answer below, not sure if it is the best solution possible, if anyone else can think of a better one, I will accept it instead.

Comment: Have you looked in the process that populates the `FEATURES` table to see what is causing some rows to have invalid geometries?

Comment: @Mazhar, It's an external process that I can't change... and I would **not** really call them invalid, they are just invalid according to SQL Server's implementation.  For example: `LINESTRING(12 12 0, 12 12 5)` is invalid, that's a vertical line but SQL server thinks it should be a `POINT(12 12 0)`. So there really isn't anything I can do here except workaround it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best solution I could find by myself:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwValidGeometries]
AS
  SELECT A.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        CASE [Geometry].STIsValid() 
           WHEN 1 THEN [Geometry] 
           ELSE NULL 
        END AS 'Geo'
    FROM Features
  )
    WHERE Geo IS NOT NULL
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM vwValidGeometries WHERE Geo.STGeometryType() = 'Point'
```

This isolates the `STIsValid()` function enough that it isn't touched by any functions that will throw an error if the geometry is invalid.

I found this answer on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1f5a5638-c84c-44da-8545-828d75067db0/yet-more-problems-with-invalid-shapes?forum=sqlspatial).